# Calling function from bound function always gives me the same value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, binding, use-effect, mousetrap

I'm sure there's a really simple solution to this, but I can't figure it out.

```
 import Mousetrap from 'mousetrap';
 const Slider = ({ children }) => {
  const [activeSlide, setActiveSlide] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('mounted');

    const element = document.querySelector('#trap');
    let trap = new Mousetrap(element);

    trap.bind('left', () => {
      test();
    });
  }, []);

  const test = () => {
    console.log(activeSlide + 1);
  };
}
```

No matter what slide I am on, whenever I call `trap.bind('left', ...` it thinks I am on slide number `0` and want to go to slide number `1`. I guess it checks the value of `activeSlide` at build time, and then keeps that value, so it doesn't get updated since my function is bound? How can I make sure it always knows the currently active slide?

Comment: You didn't post what `Moustrap()` does. Your `activeSlide` variable is declared with `const` so it can't change. It doesn't look like anything actually calls that bound function, if it even is a function.

Comment: `activeSlide` is a React hook, so its value does change. Mousetrap is a JS library for hot keys - I didn't think it was important what the library does, since what I'm interested in is javascripts behaviour with bound functions.

Comment: There's no code here that actually updates the value of `activeSlide` is that somewhere else in your code base? If so can you include that here?